# pyQt error in the PYQGIS API

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-3, pyqt4

I install QGIS via OSGeo4W 32 bit on windows 7 32 bit and i want to take PYQGIS API in standalone python script.

First I have python 3.5.2 and I have before install  sip via pip and pyqt4 via gohlke booth successful.]]

After install QGIS via OSGeo4W and I create a qgis.pth file in python site-packages with the paths.

```
sys.path
['', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\python35.zip', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32', 'C:\\Users\\usename\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35-32\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\qtplugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\python\\qgis', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\resources', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\plugins', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\grass\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\grass\\modules', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\grass\\scripts', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\saga', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\saga\\dll', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\saga\\modules', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\gdal', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\gdal-dev\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.3.svn\\bin', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.3.svn\\etc\\python', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.3.svn\\etc\\python\\grass', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.3.svn\\lib', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.3.svn\\scripts', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python25', 'C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\Python27']
```

but if i try to import qgis.core show me that error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python\qgis\PyQt\QtCore.py", line 60, in <module>
    QPyNullVariant.__nonzero__ = MethodType(__nonzero__, None, QPyNullVariant)
TypeError: method expected 2 arguments, got 3
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Your pth file is not correct and for the moment QGIS use exclusively Python 2.7.x and not Python 3.x

Comment: that is the problem?

Comment: how to fix that ?

Comment: Using a Python 2.7. version.

Comment: if i use Python 2.7. version then show me error no sip module name,and i cant to install sip package on python 2.7,i think so is only for python 3.

Comment: You can install sip on Python 2.7 without problem (look in the site-package of the QGIS Python)

Comment: but i want to run script standalone out of QGIS

Comment: There are many examples of that in GIS SE

Comment: show me one,or tell me to help me

Comment: @ChrisPapas: you are coming across as quite immature and demanding here. Remember that this is a volunteer site, and there are many questions to answer, so being easy to work with and polite is in your interest.

Comment: i am newbie sorry

Comment: @gene tell me links to can i find  examples